# How to enable wired LAN when not plugged in

Tags: networking, kubuntu

I've got a bit of an odd situation:
Here's the background:

My work laptop runs Kubuntu 18.04; I use it to configure industrial devices (SLCs, PLCs, Field I/O, etc.).  I normally plug them in directly without a switch in between; during commissioning the switches are often not installed yet.

These devices, when they are fresh "out of the box" will send a BOOTP or DHCP request every few seconds.

Here's the problem:

Because these devices are silent most of the time, Kubuntu doesn't detect there is a signal on the wire, and the interface won't come up.  Or if it does it will only come up briefly, then go away again.

My current workaround is to plug in a USB NIC and let the VMWare guest (Windows 10) take over it directly.  At that point, I can just tell Windows to leave the NIC enabled all the time, then I can answer the BOOTP requests from there.

What I'd like to do is tell Linux to make the built-in NIC active even though there's nothing (apparently) plugged in.  The device is connected to the NIC, but there's just not enough traffic on the wire for Ubuntu to know something's there.

Is there a way to tell Ubuntu to "turn on" the built-in wired NIC on the motherboard even when it doesn't detect a signal on the wire?

Comment: Your question is unclear, sounds like an "XY problem". Start with `man ip;man ip-link;man ethtool`

Comment: Thanks, waltinator; that helps a lot; I really appreciate the time you took to share your experience.